# Excel formula to copy data from another sheet skipping 3 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1 sheet named Level 2. I need to copy the data from column C rows 2 through 6 into sheet named Values column B rows 2 through 6

then

copy the data from sheet Level 2 column C rows 10 through 14 into sheet Values column B rows 7 through 11

and keep repeating this for the remained of the year copying data, skipping 3 rows in the Level 2 sheet and copying again.

Basic layout is
Rows 2 through 6 contain data for Friday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday
Row 7 is the total for the week Row 8 is am average of the week.

Comment: So what's the question? Sheets("SheetName").Range("YourRange").Copy [Destination] - The rest of the code you need is looping through your data and changing the copy/destination range. Have you written anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Step` parameter of a `For ... Next` command to achieve the stagger in the source of the copy and a little math will compute the correct destination cell.

```
Sub xfer_on_stagger()
    Dim r As Long
    With Sheets("Level 2")
        For r = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row Step 8
            .Cells(r, 3).Resize(5, 1).Copy _
              Destination:=Sheets("Values").Cells(Int(r / 8) * 5 + 2, 2)
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

The destination row might be more correctly written as `Int((r - 2) / 8) * 5 + 2` but since the `Step` is 8 and there will be no in-between values, you can drop the *minus 2*.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is VBA code and not a Formula.

`Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C10").Copy [Destination]`

Or, if range is dynamic then use lastrow to find out the actual range and select it, then copy the selected items to the desired sheet and Range.

[Shortest code to find lastrow in Excel VBA](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/343500-shortest-code-finding-last-row-via-visual-basic-applications.html)